# Chaining the templates problem with passing stl container

Tags: c++

I am writing the code and error message below.

```
template<template <typename...> class container_type>
void test_int(string container_name){
    container_type<int,std::vector> container1;
    container_type<int,std::set> container2;
    container_type<int,std::list> container3;
        ...
```

main.cpp

```
test_int<ArrayList>("arraylist"); ---> error
ArrayList<int,std::Vector> test; ---> no error
 ....
```

compiler says that:

```
test.cpp:17:32: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class container_type’
container_type<int,std::vector> container1;
                            ^
test.cpp:17:32: note:   expected a type, got ‘vector’
test.cpp:18:29: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class container_type’
container_type<int,std::set> container2;
                         ^
test.cpp:18:29: note:   expected a type, got ‘set’
test.cpp:19:30: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class container_type’
container_type<int,std::list> container3;
```

ArrayList

```
template<typename T,template <typename...> class Container>
class ArrayList : public list<T,Container>
{....
private:
    Container<T> array;
```

How Can I solve this ?
Container array works correctly, same logic, Im passing a ArrayList template to function ?

Comment: What is `ArrayList`?

Comment: Templated class, in main no error comment is works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you declared a function template where the template-template parameter `container_type` accepts an arbitrary number of *types*, but you're passing a type and a class template (`std::vector`). In order to make it accept `std::vector` and `std::set` you need to use a template-template parameter as the second parameter of the `container_type` template parameter, i.e. change the template to

```
template <template <typename, template <typename...> typename> typename container_type>
void test_int(std::string container_name) {
    container_type<int, std::vector> container1;
    container_type<int, std::set> container2;
    container_type<int, std::list> container3
}
```

which now compiles fine as you can see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aBvONUwJFhjeEjAl).

Comment: In English, for long template line, I am waiting for a template that accepts a primitive type and a template. But in Arraylist, In English meaning is same. ArrayList accepts a primitvie type and a template(vector,list,set). Isn't this a same situation ? Thank you, worked

Comment: @G.Akin It is easiest to just compare the template declaration of `ArrayList` with the one of `test_int`, these two have to match. But your original code hat `template<typename T,template <typename...> class Container>` for `ArrayList` but `test_int` expected something with template declaration `template <typename...> `.

Comment: In English, your `test_int` was expecting a template that accepts  arbitrarily many types, but `ArrayList` is a template that accepts a type plus another template that accepts arbitrarilty many types.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you, for your great explanation.